# Conditional media queries

Tags: css, media-queries, conditional-statements

I need to resize and hide an element based on certain conditions, but I can't get it right.

Pseduo code:

```
If height is less than or equal to 400px : hide
If height is between 401-600 : do x
If height is greater than or equal to 601px : do y
```

I'm doing this:

```
@media only screen and (max-height: 400px) {
    /* hide */
}
@media only screen and (min-height: 401px) and (max-height: 600px) {
    /* do X */
}
@media only screen and (max-height: 601px) {
    /* do Y */
}
```

...but it always defaults to the last condition: `do Y`

Comment: If you want 'height is greater than or equal to 601px' you have to use min-height not max-height.

Comment: i was stuck at same place yesterday

 use .SubmenuEffect4 {display:none !important;} to force them

that worked for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your last condition should be min-height and not max-height. also does not need to set `and (max-height: 600px)` because the following MQ will match anyway

http://jsfiddle.net/rnrlabs/3r382qts/

```
@media only screen and (max-height: 100px) {
    .condition {
        display: none;
        visibility: hidden;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-height: 101px)  {
    .condition {
        color: red;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-height: 301px) {
    .condition {
        color: blue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@media only screen and (max-height: 601px) {
```

should be

```
@media only screen and (min-height: 601px) {
```

Because you want "If height is greater than or equal to 601px : do y" but max-height would set the *maximum* height.

Answer (score 1):

Your last condition should be `min-height` and not `max-height`:

```
@media only screen and (max-height: 400px) {
    /* hide */
}

@media only screen and (min-height: 401px) and (max-height: 600px) {
    /* do X */
}

@media only screen and (min-height: 601px) {
    /* do Y */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@media only screen and (max-height: 400px) {
     .Submenu {display:none !important;}
}
@media only screen and (min-height: 401px) and (max-height: 600px) {
    .Submenu {display:block;}
}
@media only screen and (min-height: 601px) {
     .Submenu {display:inline-block !important;}
}
```